# Force view that conforms to protocol to have a property wrapper in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to enforce certain `View`s to contain a `@Binding` property thus I created a protocol for this.

Like the following:

```
protocol DismissableView: View {
   var isPresented: Binding<Bool> { get set }
}
```

And when I want my View to conform to it, Like this:

```
struct MyView: DismissableView {
   @Binding var isPresented: Bool 
}
```

I get the following:

```
Type 'MyView' does not conform to protocol 'DismissableView'
```

which I reckon is got to do with the fact that `@Binding` is not the same as `Binding<Bool>`

As you all are obviously aware of the fact that I cannot decalare a propertyWrapper in a protocol thus I am unable to simply declare in the protocol a @Binding directly, I am pretty stuck here.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible variants:

a) use stored property the same as in protocol (drawback: access via `wrappedValue`)

```
struct MyView: DismissableView {

    var isPresented: Binding<Bool>

    var body: some View {
        Text(isPresented.wrappedValue ? "Presented" : "Not")
    }
}
```

2. use internal variable with wrapper to conform to protocol (drawback: needed wrapper in each confirmed view)

```
struct MyView: DismissableView {

    var isPresented: Binding<Bool> {
        get { _presented }
        set { _presented = newValue }
    }

    @Binding var presented: Bool

// optional init if needed to have MyView(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) interface

//    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
//       self._presented = isPresented
//    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(presented ? "Presented" : "Not")
    }
}
```

External usage in both cases is same.

Note: the `@Binding var isPresented: Bool` property wrapper being unwrapped creates two properties (see below) that is why you cannot confirm it directly

```
var isPresented: Bool
var _isPresented: Binding<Bool>
```